# How to load more images to memory with flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

When I was training my model with data loaded by flow_from_directory with tensorflow, I accidentally deleted a few images from my training set directory, and it soon gave me the warning that it cannot find the file.

so it seems like it is actually reading the images during training, but since my dataset is not a large one, and my memory is only 40% used, I hope to slightly increase my training speed. Is there a way to tell tensorflow to prefetch more images to memory before training starts instead of reading images that current batch needs? Or is there an intentional reason that my memory is not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change some of the parameters like `batch_size` in `flow_from_directory` which is default to `32`.
And also after creating dataset you can increase the batch size and prefetch batches number also here `dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)`
If your dataset is small you can cache the dataset using `dataset.cache()` after loading and preprocessing data but before `shuffling,repeating,batching, and prefetching` so that each instance will be read and preprocessed once instead of once per epoch.

You can also check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#top_of_page) documentation to optimize working with `tf.data`